# python: can't open file 'scriptbootstrap.py'

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, electron

I am trying to start the electron app on windows via https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/development/build-instructions-windows.md

I have completed the first two steps successfully and is stuck at the building section.

When I try to run `python script\build.py`, the following errors occur:

```
python: can't open file 'scriptbootstrap.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

and not just this command specifically. Any command along that line such as `python script\build.py -c D` i run, gets me into trouble as well. I am running the command via windows bash

I think it should be looking for script/bootstrap.py but instead look for

Comment: This file does not exist or you do not have the rights to access it.

Comment: thanks for your comment. the file exist in script/bootstrap.py but it instead looking at scriptbootstrap.py

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like to know whether the `python script\bootstrap.py -v` worked for you.

See sample output, on my machine, (using git bash)

```
Anubhavs@DDSPL1392 MINGW64 /e/Projects/electron (master)
$ python script/bootstrap.py -v
Submodule 'vendor/boto' (https://github.com/boto/boto.git) registered for path 'vendor/boto'
Submodule 'vendor/breakpad' (https://github.com/electron/chromium-breakpad.git) registered for path 'vendor/breakpad'
Submodule 'vendor/brightray' (https://github.com/electron/brightray.git) registered for path 'vendor/brightray'
Submodule 'vendor/crashpad' (https://github.com/electron/crashpad.git) registered for path 'vendor/crashpad'
Submodule 'vendor/depot_tools' (https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git) registered for path 'vendor/depot_tools'
Submodule 'vendor/native_mate' (https://github.com/zcbenz/native-mate.git) registered for path 'vendor/native_mate'
Submodule 'vendor/node' (https://github.com/electron/node.git) registered for path 'vendor/node'
Submodule 'vendor/requests' (https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) registered for path 'vendor/requests'
Cloning into 'vendor/boto'...
remote: Counting objects: 42186, done.
<more lines cloning different dependencies.>
.
.
.
```

Second,
I would recommend using '/' in paths instead of '\' . This works well in windows cmd. But, is not how paths are handled across different scripts. '/' always works.

Run both commands, `python script\bootstrap.py -v` as `python script/bootstrap.py -v`, and `python script\build.py` as `python script/build.py`